# In Gmail, how can I create contact group from email recipients?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

In Gmail, is there anyway to take an email I have sent and convert all of the people on the bcc line to a contact group?  I would have thought this would be a feature but I can't seem to find this anywhere.